# Keyboard Hook in Windows DLL not getting key-up message

Tags: windows, visual-c++, keyboard, hook

In a Windows native DLL running inside an application, I've installed a keyboard hook with the following callback procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK onKeyHookEvent_(int code, WPARAM keyCode, LPARAM keyFlags)
{
    if (code < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, keyCode, keyFlags);

    if (keyFlags & KF_UP)
        doSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

But the procedure never gets a keyFlags with the KF_UP bit(s) set.  My fear is that the main application is somehow "swallowing" the release events before they get to my hook.

Is there anything else I must do to make a keyboard hook sensitive to key releases?

Comment: Possibly not related, but your `return 0` should be `return CallNextHookEx(..., code, keyCode, keyFlags);` - otherwise your hook is eating the notification and not forwarding it for further processing.

Comment: KF_UP is a flag for the WM_KEYDOWN/UP message.  Which has nothing to do with the LPARAM value you get from a WH_KEYBOARD or WM_KEYBOARD_LL hook.  What hook you use isn't visible from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the KF_UP mask must be shifted into the high position of a 32-bit word.  The correct code:

```
static const long keyUpMask = static_cast<long>(KF_UP) << 16;

...

if (keyFlags & keyUpMask)
    doSomething();
```

The weird thing is, I see no mention of this in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on KeyboardProc callbacks.

Comment: A search suggests that the usual formula is (HIWORD(keyFlags) & KF_UP), but of course this is equivalent.

Comment: Mind sharing where you found that?  I had a hard time getting this info - it was basically trial and error.

Comment: Searched MSDN for KF_UP.  The fourth match was a forum thread which contained this suggestion (from Hans, as it happens).  The actual documentation does list the correct bit layout for lParam but fails to mention that the constants defined in WinUser.h (such as KF_UP) are 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a low level keyboard hook([Low Level KeyboardProc MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=VS.85%29.aspx/)). You will be able to process `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` messages. But I don't know if you are looking for something like this, or something else. I used this once with a keylogger program in assembly and it worked perfectly for key presses and releases.